# Do I need to synchronize my destructor with async functions when using PPL?

Tags: c++-cx, ppl

Let's say I have a ViewModel that can be destroyed when a user navigates away from its bound View. The destructor performs cleanup on a subscription member variable:

```
MyViewModel::~MyViewModel()
{
    if (m_subscription)
    {
        if (m_contentChangedToken.Value != 0)
        {
            m_subscription->ContentChanged -= m_contentChangedToken;
            m_contentChangedToken.Value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

After the ViewModel is created, a function runs which asynchronously gets the subscription, assigns it to a member variable, and assigns event listeners

```
void MyViewModel::AwesomeFunctionAsync()
{
    create_task(TargetedContentSubscription::GetAsync(c_subId))
        .then([this](TargetedContentSubscription^ subscription)
    {
        if (subscription)
        {
            m_subscription = subscription;
            m_contentChangedToken = m_subscription->ContentChanged += // attach event
        }
    }, task_continuation_context::use_arbitrary());
}
```

Now let's say my ViewModel is being destroyed while a background thread is running code inside AwesomeFunctionAsync. Is there a race condition lurking here? For instance, might the destructor run before the event is attached by the background thread? Or can I trust the destructor is always last due to the GC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone explicitly tries to `delete` the object, you will be fine since the lambda captures the `this` pointer and will keep it alive.

For example, try the following simple test:

```
ref struct TestClass sealed
{
  void DoStuffAsync()
  {
    concurrency::create_async([this]()
    {
      Sleep(1000);
      PrintValue();
    });
  }

  void PrintValue()
  {
    // Accessing 'name' after deletion is undefined behavior, but it 
    // "works on my machine" for the purposes of this demonstration.
    std::string message = name + ": PrintValue is running.";

    // Accessing 'data.size()' after deletion is also undefined behavior
    if (data.size() == 0)
    {
      message += " Oops, I'm about to crash\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
      message = message + " Data is " + std::to_string(data[0]) + 
        ", " + std::to_string(data[1]) + "\r\n";
    }

    OutputDebugStringA(message.c_str());
  }

  virtual ~TestClass()
  {
    std::string message = name + ": Destructor is running.\r\n";
    OutputDebugStringA(message.c_str());
  }

internal: // so we can use 'const char *'

  TestClass(const char* name) : name{ name }, data{ 1, 2 }
  {
    std::string message = this->name + ": Constructor is running.\r\n";
    OutputDebugStringA(message.c_str());
  }

private:
  std::string name;
  std::vector<int> data;
};

void Test()
{
  OutputDebugStringA("Starting 'no async' test\r\n");
  {
    auto c = ref new TestClass("no async");
    c->PrintValue();
  }
  OutputDebugStringA("---\r\nDone. Starting 'async' test\r\n");

  {
    auto c = ref new TestClass("async");
    c->DoStuffAsync();
  }
  OutputDebugStringA("---\r\nDone. Starting 'explicit delete' test\r\n");

  {
    auto c = ref new TestClass("explicit delete");
    c->DoStuffAsync();
    delete c;
  }
}


MainPage::MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  Test();
}
```

When you run it, you will see something like this in the Output window:

```
Starting 'no async' test 
no async: Constructor is running. 
no async: PrintValue is running. Data is 1, 2 
no async: Destructor is running.
--- Done. Starting 'async' test 
async: Constructor is running.
--- Done. Starting 'explicit delete' test 
explicit delete: Constructor is running. 
explicit delete: Destructor is running. 
async: PrintValue is running. Data is 1, 2 
: PrintValue is running. Oops, I'm about to crash 
async: Destructor is running.
```

Note the `'async'` version doesn't run the destructor until after `PrintValue` has run asynchronously. But the `'explicit delete'` version destroys the object, which will crash when it tries to access member variables approximately 1 second later. (You can see that accessing `name` doesn't crash -- although it's undefined behavior -- but if you tried to access the elements of `data` you would get an exception (or worse)).